# Relation between summing over an infinite but countable set of elements, limits, integrals

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, asymptotics

Consider a sequence $\{a_i\}_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$. I would like your help to understand the relation among

(1) $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_i$

(2) $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n a_i$

(3) Riemann integral

(4) Integrating over an *uncountably infinite* set

---

More context:

I am asking this because I have derived some results that hold when $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i$ enters my problem. The professor asked me to extend those results to the infinite case and I don't know whether (A) I should replace $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i$ with $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_i$, (B) I should replace $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i$ with $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i$, (C) I should replace $i\in \{1,2,...,n\}$ with $i\in \mathcal{I}$ and $\mathcal{I}$ uncountably infinite (and then I replace the sum with an integral?). I'm a beginner of asymptotics.

Comment: You can't sum over an uncountable set unless $a_i=0$ for all but countably many terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, usually, the definition of $1$ is $2$, i.e the infinite sum is defined as the limit of the finite sums.

The Riemann integral is defined as the limit of finite sums. Sums over uncountable sets are **not defined**. Specifically, if you have an interval $[a,b]$, you chop it up/partition it using the set $\{a =x_0, \cdots , x_n = b\}$. then you pick points $t_i$ between each $x_i,x_{i+1}$. You then define Riemann sums

$$
\sum_{i = 0}^{n} f(t_i) (x_{i+1} - x_i)
$$ 
for any partition. You take the limit then as the mesh of the partition approaches $0$. By the mesh, we mean the maximum distance between any two points in the partition, i.e $\mathrm{mesh} (P) = \max_{0 \leq i \leq n-1}(x_{i+1} - x_i)$. Hopefully this makes some sense.

Comment: Thanks. So, what is $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_i$ written as Riemann integral?

Comment: What do you mean? Are you asking how we can relate an infinite sum to the Riemann integral of a function?

Answer (score 0):

If your result is about $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i$ and he says "the infinite case" I would expect it to mean $\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i$.